# Adapter doesn't call getChildView android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to develop 3 level down expanable list view but got stuck after inflating the first level item not able to see child of the first level.

Only showing the parent view not showing the second level view not even any click event occurs.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ofd.R;
import com.ofd.base.BaseFragment;
import com.ofd.utils.Utils;

import static com.ofd.utils.Constants.LEFT_ICON_PREVIOUS;
import static com.ofd.utils.Constants.NONE;

/*
 * This fragment is used to show the Agencies expanable list
 * 
 * @author girish.sharma
 *
 */

public class AgenciesFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    private View view;
    private Button mSubmit;
    public static int Service = -1;
    private Context mContext;

    ExpandableListView explvlist;
    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    /**
     * This is the function used to initialize the view of the fragment
     ***/
    @Override
    protected View initUI(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agencies_fragment, null);
            mContext = getActivity();
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            explvlist = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ParentLevel);
            explvlist.setAdapter(new ParentLevel());
            explvlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        super.onItemClick(adapterView, arg1, position, arg3);
        Utils.showToast(mContext, "Click");
    }

    public class ParentLevel extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {

            return arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            CustExpListview SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(mContext);
            SecondLevelexplv.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter());
            SecondLevelexplv.setGroupIndicator(null);
            return SecondLevelexplv;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService
                        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, parent, false);
                // Inflate the layout that you want for each row
                /*convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, parent, false);*/
                /*mViewHolder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitleMain);*/

                // Add a reference in ViewHolder for your Button, find it like the TextViews and define its OnClickListener here too, eventually...
                /*view.setTag(mViewHolder);*/
            } /*else
                mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();*/
            mViewHolder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitleMain);

            mViewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText("FirstLevel");
            /*TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            tv.setText("->FirstLevel");
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setPadding(10, 7, 7, 7);*/

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class CustExpListview extends ExpandableListView {

        int intGroupPosition, intChildPosition, intGroupid;

        public CustExpListview(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(960, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            tv.setText("child");
            tv.setPadding(15, 5, 5, 5);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            return tv;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            tv.setText("-->Second Level");
            tv.setPadding(12, 7, 7, 7);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            return tv;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here change the header text
     ***/
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        TitleBarFragment fragment = (TitleBarFragment) getFragment(R.id.activity_fragment_launcher_header);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setTitleBarVisibility(true);
            fragment.setHeaderTitleAndSideIcon(getActivity().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.fragment_agencies_header),
                    LEFT_ICON_PREVIOUS, NONE);
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtViewTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not well implementing view holder pattern

Comment: Yes, Its just a run time code trying mutiple things to make it working.

Comment: Code works fine if I keep only textview in the Item.
But I need to inflate texview and checkbox in the item of  List.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to find the same issue, only to realise it was something dead simple on my side:

1. For some reason (and I will debug it now) - the groupview did not expand when touch it.
2. Since the group view is not expanded, there is NO reason to waste CPU cycles to fetch a view that will not be displayed.
3. All of the methods in the adapter relating to the children is not called.

Try calling explvlist.expandGroup(0...n) to manually expand it and see if it called the child-related methods in the adapter.